# rxjava, cannot resolve symbol ‘just’ in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

[image]

It works in:

```
Observable<String> observable = Observable.just("");
```

But cannot resolve symbol `just` in `Observable.just("");`

I'm sure I have imported the `rxjava2.jar`, and the `Observable.just("")` does well in Eclipse but not in IDEA.

Comment: Please read the help topics on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards, please update your question with the code you have written thus far.

Comment: Read up on Java Generics. The key to your problem lies there.

Comment: @gpgekko the same codes work well in eclipse and android studio, but IDEA. I think it not about the java generics

Comment: That's funny, because Android Studio is IntelliJ IDEA based.

Comment: @QuintinBalsdon thanks for your answer, it's my first Time to be here, and a picture is behind the title, that maybe clearly. By the way, it's not help.

Comment: @gpgekko yeah, but it's true, I don't know how to do

Comment: It's my fault that I wrote the codes out of main()，and it's correct in main()

Answer (score 1):

File -> Project Structure -> Module -> + button click -> Library -> Maven

Searchbox -> Rx Java

by applying the stages to your project.

[Maven Repos](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.reactivex/rxjava)

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same issue; I also saw similar behavior in the past, which drove me crazy for a long time, resulting in reinstalling the IDE.

Turns out, the problem was due to IntelliJ's `idea.max.intellisense.filesize` setting.  I had set it to 100KB, which was smaller than Observable's size.

This leads to weird results in IDEA/IntelliJ (mostly to the IDE not being able to find code/sources that are in the classpath.)

Answer (score 0):

when you wanna import observable you must select import io.reactivex.Observable;
but you selected import android.database.Observable mistakenly.

i hope this hint helps you